# Sigmund Freud's Jewish Name

Tags: names, historical-figures

What was the eminent Psychologist, and father of Psychoanalysis' Jewish Name (as when they called him up to the Torah)?

Answer (score 6):

According to Emanuel Rice's biography *Freud and Moses: The Long Journey Home*, Sigmund Freud was given the Hebrew name Shlomo by his father Jacob, given that baby Sigmund was born a few months after his paternal grandfather Shlomo died in 1856.

As for getting called up to the Torah...from the historical evidence, it's highly unlikely that ever happened. The historian Yosef Hayim Yerushalmi, in his work *Freud's Moses*, goes to great lengths to determine if Freud even underwent a Bar Mitzvah ceremony, the only possible occasion for an aliyah, but there is no definitive evidence that it occurred.